# What type of data can I send via a NetStream?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server

I know I can attach audio and video to a NetStream. Apparently, I can also attach text messages although I haven't seen an example (if you know of one, please let me know). I also know that I can record a stream via Flash Media Server. I'm wondering what other types of data – if anything – else I can attach to a NetStream and record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can send almost anything (depends on the recieving side) using [NetStream.send()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/NetStream.html#send%28%29)